# How to run .net code when a user unlocks a Windows machine?

Tags: .net, windows-7, windows-xp, unlock

How do I run .net code when a user unlocks their machine?

Windows versions: XP and 7

Comment: Poor Vista. Always a bridesmaid, never a bride.

Comment: Vista AKA "Windows 7 Alpha 1"

Comment: This is not a serverfault question, it's about getting an event notification on workstation unlock.

Comment: The question is unclear about whether he wants an event notification to a running app or script execution on session unlock.

Comment: @Graphain: Seemed clear to me.  It would probably be best to ask for clarification if unsure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This article looks perfect for you if you want to subscribe to the session lock/unlock events (e.g. how Messenger sets your status to away when you lock your PC).

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/05/17/418891.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20150806234322/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/05/17/418891.aspx)

Alternatively, you can run a script on Windows 7 unlock as per this ServerFault question: https://serverfault.com/questions/148258/run-a-script-after-i-unlock-my-windows-session

Answer (score 3):

MattMitchell is right that the article he suggests might help you.

On the chance that it doesn't, in a general sense you're looking for information on the [ISensLogon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376860%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface, which is what allows you to monitor the events you're looking for.  If you search for ISensLogon on google, you'll find a lot of articles about a lot of different ways to use it, at least one of which will probably help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's too bad you have to support XP as well. There's a nice scheduled task capability in Windows 7 that includes triggering it on workstation unlock. Would be just a few lines of code... and you could include things like "don't do it if the machine is on battery" too.